# Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined while using moment in laravel with vue js

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js, momentjs

im using laravel 5 and i installed moment js through npm install command. im trying to use it in one of my views with vue js. but no matter what i do i get error "moment is not defined" and if i use require, i get "require is not defined" below is the script section of my view.
`

```
<script>
    var order = new Vue({
        el: '#create_order',

        data: {
            moment: moment,
            event_id: '',
            event_type: '',
            ticket_types: [],
            time_slots: [],
            current_timeslots: [],
            start_date: null,
            end_date: null
        },

        methods: {
            moment: function (date) {
                return moment(date);
            },`
```

im beginner at this so please be as explanatory as possible, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

I use the following way. In app.js I add

```
window.moment = require('moment');
window.moment.locale('ru');
```

Comment: is this app.js in resources->assets->js->app.js ? and do i have to do anything in the view? because im still getting moment is not defined

Answer (score 4):

You should import moment library before starting to use it.

You can try code below

```
<script>
   import moment from 'moment'
   var order = new Vue({
   ...
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but now im getting "unexpected token import"